# How to send a 1 dimensional integer array from QML to C++?

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, qt, qml

So I have a signal:

QML:

```
signal qmlSendWorkflowIdsArraySignal(variant workflowIdsArray)
```

JS:

```
sendToCppWorkflowIdsArray(arrayOfWorkflowIds);
```

C++:

```
QObject::connect(qmlMainContentItemObject, SIGNAL(qmlSendWorkflowIdsArraySignal(QVariant)), &myController, SLOT(qmlToCppWorkflowIdsArraySlot(QVariant)));
```

C++ slot:

```
void qmlToCppWorkflowIdsArraySlot(QVariant workflowIdsArray)
{
  qDebug() << " +++++++++++++++ Cpp Array slot has been called: "<<workflowIdsArray;
}
```

**Output:**

```
+++++++++++++++ Cpp Array slot has been called:
QVariant(QVariantList, (QVariant(QString, "2") ,  QVariant(QString, "3") ,  QVariant(QString, "4") ) )
```

- How do I read this QVariantList inside QVariant, ie, lets say I want
  to read this first element of the array, that is QVariant(QString,
  “2”), then the other and the other. This looks very complicated like
  this.
- All I need is to pass an array of integers from QML to C++, so    I
  can read this array. I dont want to use QVariant or a QVariantList,  unless I have to as I see no other way to do it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to pass an array from QML to C++ is as follows:

Create a class which is going to receive that integer array:

***DataReceiver.h***

```
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QList>

class Receiver : public QQuickItem
{
private:
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY (QList<int> xx READ xx WRITE setXX NOTIFY xxChanged)
    QList<int> m_xx;

public:
    Receiver (QQuickItem *parent = 0) {}

    QList<int> xx() const
    {
        return m_xx;
    }

public slots:
    void setXX (QList<int> arg)
    {
        if (m_xx != arg) {
            m_xx = arg;
            emit xxChanged (arg);
        }
    }

signals:
    void xxChanged (QList<int> arg);
};
```

***In main.cpp***

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "DataReceiver.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    const char* ui = "HELLO"; // @uri HELLO
    qmlRegisterType <Receiver> (ui, 1, 0, "DataReceiver");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

***In QML (main.qml)***

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import HELLO 1.0

Window 
{
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360

    id: head

    property variant myArray: [1,2,3]

    DataReceiver
    {
         id: dataReceiver
         xx: head.myArray
    } 
}
```

You might also like to check this:
[How to push values to QML property variant two dimensional array - dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098663/how-to-push-values-to-qml-property-variant-two-dimensional-array-dynamically)

Comment: Yep, using properties is even better than Q_INVOKABLE methods, as property bindings are more declarative than imperatively calling some method.

Comment: Just to be clear on what to use,I will ask you one more question: I also have a QML with lots of buttons and other controls. Once a button is clicked I want to send to C++, the objectName of the button that I clicked in QML. Then C++ should call a method, which checks the objectName of the buttonClicked and then does something. You have described very nicely up there how to send an array from QML to C++.I was wondering if there is something similar for sending the objectName onButtonClicked. Right now I am using signals and slots for everything. It works good,but its my thesis,I want the best.

Comment: @mshefiti There is no need to send any object name anywhere. You can simply declare an  unique ID for each button and send that ID wherever you want.

Comment: thank you for your answer, its quite helpful @TheIndependentAquarius

Comment: thank you @tmcguire, I also tried Q_Invokable which works perfectly fine, but in my case it makes more sense to use property bindings.

Answer (score 6):

QML supports conversion between QList and Javascript values, for a limited amount of types. See the [documentation on type conversion](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html) for details. No need to use QVariant for these.

With that, calling C++ methods from JS is easy:

tester.h:

```
class Tester : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void bla(const QList<QString> &strings) {
        qDebug() << "Tester::bla():" << strings;
    }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
Tester tester;
viewer.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("_tester", &tester);
```

QML:

```
onClicked: _tester.bla(["asdf", "foo", "bar"]);
```

Note that I didn't use a signal here - in your case, the signal was connected from the C++ code, where the C++ code accessed an object from the QML layer. I try to avoid that, to force a cleaner separation between the C++ and QML layers, which makes it possible to completely change the QML code without needing to adapt the C++ layer. The C++ layer should never reach into the QML layer, the other way around is fine though.

Comment: In tester.cpp I want to implement a big lets say bla() method, what is the syntax for that? Is it:  `void tester::bla(const QList<QString> &strings) { ........} ` ?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to move the implementation of `bla()` from in-class in the .h file to out-of-class in the .cpp file?
That would indeed be `void Tester::bla(const QList<QString> &strings) { ... }` in the .cpp file.

Comment: **IMPORTANT NOTE:** I can't achieve the result without `const` keyword.